What is the minimal Tukey depth of a convex planar set?
The Tukey depth of a point $x$ within a finite set $S$ of points in the plane is the minimum fraction of the points in $S$ contained within a closed half-plane passing through $x$. The Tukey median is the point (not necessarily unique) with maximal Tukey depth.
We can easily generalize this to the case of a compact convex set $C$ in the plane: the Tukey depth of a point $x$ is the minimum of $\text{Area}(H\cap C)/\text{Area}(C)$ over all half-planes $H$ passing through $x$. Abusing terminology a bit, say that the Tukey depth of $C$ is the Tukey depth of its median or medians.
I am curious about lower bounds that can be put on the Tukey depth of a convex planar set. It's obvious that the largest possible value is $1/2$, attained by all centrally symmetric sets, but the lower bound is less clear.
I believe that all triangles attain a Tukey depth of $4/9$, and I don't know of any convex sets that score lower but haven't searched very hard.
By the Kovner-Besicovich theorem, taking $x$ as the center of the maximal centrally-symmetric subset in $C$ gives a Tukey depth of at least $1/3$. However, I strongly suspect this bound is not sharp, and the true answer is closer to the $4/9$ attained by triangles.
Has this question been investigated in the literature? Are there relevant theorems about this measure for non-finite point sets?

For finite sets, it sounds like Helly's theorem gives a lower bound of $1/3$. This is tight (e.g. three points in an equilateral triangle).
This doesn't give a tight bound for convex sets, but maybe Helly's theorem can be applied to them directly to get a better bound?
